# assembly 8086 - score isn't working properly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm trying to print this score to create a game and the score prints just in one side,(when I increment
scores,it prints the score just in one side,the other one stays zero.This is the code,thanks.

```
proc print_score
    ; prints the points in the middle of the screen:

    ; set cursor to the middle:
    mov  dl, 170  
    mov  dh, 45   
    mov  bh, 0
    mov  ah, 02h  
    int  10h
    ; print scores, knowing it can be 0-9 (aka one char):
    mov al, [Score1]
    mov bl, 0Fh
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 0eh
    add al, '0'
    int 10h

    ; score1:score2
    mov al, ':'
    mov bl, 0Fh
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 0Eh
    int 10h

    mov al, [Score2]
    mov bl, 0Fh
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 0eh
    add al, '0'
    int 10h

    ret
endp print_score

    proc check_goal
    pusha
;if player 1 scores to player2 inc his score
check_goal_player1:
    cmp [ballX],315d
    ja  goal_1

    jmp check_goal_player2

goal_1:
    inc [score1]

    call refrash
    ;call player_2_scored

    jmp new_round

check_goal_player2:
    cmp [ballX],0d
    jb goal_2

    jmp no_update

goal_2:

    inc [score2]
    call refrash

    ;call player_1_scored
new_round:


    call restore_ball_possition
    jmp no_update

no_update:


    popa
    ret
endp check_goal
```

Comment: The printing code looks the same for both halves (except for Score1 vs. Score2), so likely the problem is somewhere else.  Use a debugger to look at the values in memory (and registers).  If Score2 isn't being incremented, then this code that correctly(?) prints what's there is not a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Does the colon print? Or just the value for `Score1`?

Comment: It,should print the value for score1 and 2 both.It should print it in 2 places (score1:score2) when I increment score one or two,it prints the score just in one side

Comment: But you didn't answer my question. Does it print the separator between the two scores? Does it always print Score1? Or does it always print Score2? How are `Score1` and `Score2` defined? Are you sure that you're saving the scores correctly? Have you run the code in the debugger to see what's in `[Score1]` and `[Score2]`. It's highly unlikely that the printing code you've shown is the problem, so it's difficult to help you unless you can answer our questions or give us more code to look at.

Comment: Thanks,I'll try to debug the proc.It simply prints the separator between 2 scores.The scores are defined as bytes (db)

Comment: Steel it is not working... please help me with this problem. I've sent the sec proc that increments the score but I steel think that the problem is in the first proc that prints the score and not about incrementing the score.

Comment: Thank you all.It was problem with check_goal proc.

Answer (score 2):

### Something that is most troubling.

> ```
> ; prints the points in the middle of the screen:
> ; set cursor to the middle:
> mov  dl, 170  
> mov  dh, 45   
> mov  bh, 0
> mov  ah, 02h  
> int  10h
> ```

The BIOS.SetCursor function 02h expects you to pass *character cell coordinates* for the desired cursor position. The number of character cells on a row can never exceed 255 and the same limit applies to the row coordinate. If you say that you aim for the middle of the screen and pass a value of 170 for the column coordinate, your screen would have about 340 columns! That's not possible with this BIOS call. Are you confused beween character coordinates and pixel coordinates?

e.g. The middle of the 320x200 256 color screen has cursor coordinate (20,12) because there are just 40 columns and 25 rows.

### The reason why the 2nd score stays zero

> ```
> check_goal_player2:
>     cmp [ballX],0d
>     jb goal_2
>     jmp no_update
> goal_2:
>     inc [score2]
> ```

When you compare some value with 0, you can **never** get the *below* condition code. Therefore the `jb goal_2` instruction will **never** jump to where you would like to increment *score2*.

Seeing `cmp [ballX], 315` `ja goal_1` and with symmetry in mind, my guess is that you're using a 320 pixels wide screen. Perhaps the solution is to write `cmp [ballX], 4` `jb goal_2` ?